# getting bundler load error frequently and no such file Gemfile error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, ruby-on-rails-4.2, docker-machine

Below is the docker file in project's root directory:-

```
FROM ruby:2.2
MAINTAINER technologies.com

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential

RUN apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev

RUN apt-get install -y libqt4-webkit libqt4-dev xvfb

RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

ENV INSTALL_PATH /as_app

RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY Gemfile Gemfile

RUN bundle install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Below is the contents in docker-compose.yml file in project's root directory :-

```
as_web:
  build: .
  environment:
    - RAILS_ENV=development
    - QUEUE=*
    - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
  volumes:
    - .:/as_app
  ports:
    - 3000:3000
  links:
    - as_mongo
    - as_redis
  command: rails server -b 0.0.0.0
as_mongo:
  image: mongo:latest
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
as_redis:
  image: redis
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
as_worker:
  build: .
  environment:
    - QUEUE=*
    - RAILS_ENV=development
    - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
  volumes:
    - .:/as_app
  links:
    - as_mongo
    - as_redis
  command: bundle exec rake environment resque:work
```

docker version 1.11.2, docker-machine version 0.8.0-rc1, docker-compose version 1.8.0-rc1, ruby 2.2.5, rails 4.2.4.

My problem is as:-

1) When I build the image with "docker-compose build" from project root directory the image builds successfully with gems installed.
2) But when I do "docker-compose up" the as_web and as_worker services exits with code 1 and 10 resp. giving error as no gemfile or .bundler found. When I login in image through bash and see the working directory then no project files are seen.

3) Knowledge I want to know is:-

i) when I start terminal, I start VirtualBox instance manually like "docker-machine start default"
  ii) Then I execute command "eval $(docker-machine env dev)" to point current shell to virtualbox docker-daemon, So after this when i do "docker build -t as_web ." the terminal gives message like "sending current build context to docker daemon",

a) Is this message saying that build in being done in VirtualBox ?

if I do "docker-compose build" no such message like "sending...." appears,

B) Does docker-compose too point to docker daemon in virtual box or it's being build in localhost(myubuntuOS), I'm little bit confused?

Hoping you guys understood the details if you need any extra  info. then let me know, Thanking you all. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose build` and `docker build` both do the same thing. They both use the docker engine API to build an image in the virtualbox. The output messages are just a little different.

Your problem is because of this:

```
 volumes:
- .:/as_app
```

You're overriding the app directory with the project directory from the host. If you haven't run bundle install on the host, the files won't be in the container when it starts.

You can fix this by running `docker-compose run as_app bundle install`